# Use already existing VM with TPU

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-tpu, tpu

According to [ctpu documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tpu/tree/master/tools/ctpu) I can use following commands: `status`, `up`, `pause` and `delete`, where `up` does the following " ctpu up will create a Compute Engine VM with TensorFlow pre-installed".
However, I already have a VM on GCP I am working with. All my machine learning scripts are there. I even executed them successfully but they execute slow and I want to use preemptible TPU.
How can I connect my VM to use TPU instead of creating new VM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the `--tpu-only` flag - see [CTPU Reference](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/ctpu-reference).

Comment: Thanks. I created the TPU manually from the GCP console. Now I have VM, Cloud Storage Bucket and TPU in the same region. I am not sure, however, should I connect them somehow? For example, when I run my tensorflow model training on the VM will it use TPU?

Comment: Yes, it should as long as you specify the name of the TPU in the same region as this [flag](https://github.com/tensorflow/tpu/blob/master/models/official/resnet/resnet_main.py#L64) the [TPUClusterResolver](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/cluster_resolver/TPUClusterResolver) will resolve that name to the actual address of the TPU server.

Comment: The tensorflow command line flag linked above was --tpu
https://github.com/tensorflow/tpu/blob/be55b81fa27f30308c28ff4710e9bcac40321d5b/models/official/resnet/resnet_main.py#L63